# Referring css and js files from sub domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I has one website with a theme that uses it's own stylesheet and javascript.

I want to create multiple sub domains that uses different theme from the main site.

When i have created a subdomain and was referring sub domain css and js files, it is not able to find it

I want sub-domain to refer different theme than main site theme

My main site is under 
public_html/example
public_html/example/css
public_html/example/css/exm.css

My SubDomain has following hierarchy
public_html/example/subdomain/sub1
public_html/example/subdomain/sub2

and css and js are under
public_html/example/subdomain
public_html/example/subdomain/css
public_html/example/subdomain/css/exm.css

public_html/example/subdomain/sub1/index.html

So i want to refer exm.css from index.html from sub/index.html

Comment: Please post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same `index.php` for all pages but just want to include different CSS and Javascript files depending on the current subdomain, you can use `HTTP_HOST` to extract it and then include the corresponding files. You'd store them in `your.domain.com/sub/js/theme.js` and `your.domain.com/sub/css/theme.css`

PHP:

```
$includePath = "/";
// array(0 => "sub", 1 => "example", 2 => "com");
$domainParts = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$domainPartsCount = count($domainParts);
if ($domainPartsCount >= 3)
    $includePath .= $domainParts[$domainPartsCount - 3] . "/";
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $includePath ?>css/theme.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $includePath ?>js/theme.js"></script>
</head>
```